# Ruby on Rails application deployment on local computer with postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am new to Ruby on Rails. We have developed an small application with Postgresql. Now we have to deploy it. But when i searched over internet i found lot of suggestion is to deploy them on Heroku or some premium servers. where we are not in a position now to deploy it on cloud.

How can i deploy the application on local computer? Is this similar to setting up a development environment?

Any link or lead will be much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, it is similar to setting up a development environment

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have your application already running on your development environment. 
Create another database in your postgres, to use it for production in local system. And make necessary changes in database.yml

I feel passenger is the easiest way to deploy application, you can follow the steps in this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-passenger-and-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04 to deploy your app.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku also have free deployment for few application. You can use heroku.

There are some more option like AWS, Digital Ocean. AWS is also free for one year.

Yes setting up a development environment is like set up your environment. But best practice is use a deployment automation like [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano).

Answer (score 0):

You can run it in a production environment and make it public. I had written a blog post regarding this.

Please check [here](https://railsweb.wordpress.com/2015/08/13/expose-localhost-to-internet/)

ps - Make sure your system is up for public access and i am hoping that this is for test purpose only and to show it to your clients.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be fairly similar to setting up your development environment.

In addition to setting up Passenger as described in the Digital Ocean post from [Rajuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1746270/rajuk)'s answer, I use [Capistrano](http://capistranorb.com/) for deployment to my Ubuntu servers. You can set up the Capistrano deployment configuration to deploy to any machine.

The possible configuration variables are too numerous to address here without further details about your specific situation.

Check out [Railscast #335 Deploying to a VPS](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps)  where Ryan talks about deploying to a Linux machine (a cloud VPS in this case) with Capistrano.